# Operator overloading for two number array (pointer) in C

Tags: c, operator-overloading

i would like to ask if there is a way to add 2 number array together with operator '+'
For example, I've got two pointer:
`char* arr1 //(which has {1,2,3,4})`
`char* arr2 //(which has {2,3,4,5})`
Is there a way to has a:
`char* arr3 //which has {3,5,7,9}`

Comment: C doesn't have overloading at all, let alone operator overloading.

Comment: oh, i thought it was available like in c++, thank u for your ans